# ActionScript 3 - Add and remove child from stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I am just learning ActionScript 3, so this is probaly an eazy question for you pro's. 
I created movie clips that I want to add to the stage (from the library) by the use of buttons. I have a total of six buttons (and six moviclips) but I am trying to get the first two to work before I move on to the next buttons. The problem is I can't seem to remove the movie clip when another button is clicked, or the same button... Like I said I am new at this and I think a created a mess of things... I am getting error 2007 now

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);
function addbear(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var movieClip:bear1 = new bear1();
    addChild(movieClip);
    movieClip.x = 240;
    movieClip.y = 45;


mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);
mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
}
function removebear(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var movieClip:bear1 = null;
    removeChild(movieClip);
    mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
/*  mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);*/
}
shake_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear3);
function addbear3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var movieClip:bear3 = new bear3();
    addChild(movieClip);
    movieClip.x = 240;
    movieClip.y = 45;

    shake_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear3);
    shake_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear3);
}
function removebear3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var movieClip:bear3 = null;
    removeChild(movieClip);
    shake_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear3);
    shake_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var movieClip:bear1 = null;
removeChild(movieClip);
mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
```

This part here, you basically try to remove a null object, which it's usually bad:). This applies for "snake" and other buttons or movieclips as well. If you want to remove the bear you've clicked, try this:

```
var movieClip:bear1 = bear1(event.currentTarget);
removeChild(movieClip);
mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're referencing movieClip as a function level variable, which goes away when that function complete.  When your remove function happens later, the movieclip itself still exists, but the movieclip variable you're using to reference it is gone.

If the remove event were directly on the bear, you could use event.currentTarget to access and remove it.

Instead, since it looks like your listener is on a separate button, you'll need a reference to the movieclip that works from anywhere. If you assign an instance name to the movieclip, you can use that to access and remove it later.

```
function addbear(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    var movieClip:bear1 = new bear1();
    addChild(movieClip); 
    movieClip.x = 240; 
    movieClip.y = 45;
    movieClip.name = "bear1";  
} 

function removebear(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    removeChild(getChildByName("bear1"));
}
```

Comment: It can't 'go away' as long as it's added to a display list. More than than, he uses 2 different local variables, so that surely it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely a scope issue
In your function addbear you create a var scoped to this function called movieClip

```
mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);
function addbear(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var movieClip:bear1 = new bear1();
    addChild(movieClip);
    movieClip.x = 240;
    movieClip.y = 45;


mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);
mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
}
function removebear(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var movieClip:bear1 = null;
    removeChild(movieClip);
    mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
/*  mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);*/
}
```

to correct this you need to move the scope of mopvieClip outside of the functions

```
   mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);
    var movieClip:bear1 // **********************global scoping
    function addbear(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        movieClip = new bear1(); // *************constructing new GLOBAL object here
        addChild(movieClip);
        movieClip.x = 240;
        movieClip.y = 45;


    mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);
    mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
    }
    function removebear(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        removeChild(movieClip);//****************** remove movieClip first
        movieClip= null; // **********************destroying GLOBAL object here
        mix_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removebear);
    /*  mix_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addbear);*/
    }
```